# RangeError on last Element in AnimatedList

Tags: flutter, dart

I have wanted to create a simple Todo app, with implementation of Material Design and the AnimatedList. 
I had no problems inserting an Item to the AnimatedList, removing Items was also very easy, except if i want to remove the last Item of the AnimatedList.

I have i seperated ToDo class that contains a title,description,id and a complete boolean.

The Exception:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
```

My Function to remove the item:

```
void _removeSingleItems(int index) {
int removeIndex = index;
AnimatedListRemovedItemBuilder builder = (context, animation) {
  return item(animation, removeIndex);
};
_listKey.currentState.removeItem(removeIndex, builder);
tasksTodo.removeAt(removeIndex);
}
```

AnimatedList Widget;

```
AnimatedList(
                  key: _listKey,
                  initialItemCount: tasksTodo.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
                    return item(animation, index);
                  })
```

In flutter doctor is everything fine and i also tried flutter clean, but i didn't help.
Flutter version: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.7

Full Code on Github: https://gist.github.com/Maciejfiedler/eb77de37a94458f0f4375dd56c053591

Comment: add full code of widget

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for the problem. The problem occurred, because the `_removeSingleItem` function got called 2 times. the first time in my animatedList and the second time in `_removeSingleItem` function. Just add a bool to the `item Widget`, that controlls the `onPressed Callback`. If the bool is true the `_removeSingleItem` function get called and if false it will not get called. Set to bool true in AnimatedList and to false in the `_removeSingleItem` function.